# Why path comparison is case-sensitive in latest filesystem draft (C++)?

Tags: c++, filesystems

A quote from [Programming Languages — C++ — File System Technical Specification draft N4100](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf):

> 8.4.8 pathcompare [path.compare]
>
> 1 int compare(const path& p) const noexcept;
>
> 2 Returns: A value less than 0 if native() for the elements
> of *this are lexicographically less than native() for the elements of p,
> otherwise a value greater than 0 if native()for the elements of *this are
> lexicographically greater than native() for the elements of p, otherwise 0.

Why the file path comparison is defined as case-sensitive if there are file systems that are case-insensitive (NTFS, etc)? Shouldn't comparison be done according to specific file system rules?

Comment: Probably for portability reasons? Seems to me if the library assumes case sensitivity the code will work on non-case sensitive systems but not the other way around.

Comment: Many systems can have multiple file systems with different rules.

Comment: Case-insensitive comparisons are locale sensitive.  I guess that's an added complicity they didn't want to have.

Comment: @RichardCritten Actually, Windows does non locale specific comparison of filenames. Look for `CompareStringOrdinal` at [Handling Sorting in Your Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318144%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Are you sure that `native()` is not meant to give filename encoded in system dependent way? That is in case-insensitive system it could return uppercased path.

Comment: @doc NTFS preserves filename case and when you for ex. request a list of files from OS you get the filename in the case it was created in. So "encoded in system dependent way" wouldn't be all uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: [NTFS is case-sensitive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625)

Comment: @gha.st So case-sensitivity becomes not file system specific but rather OS-specific under Windows. Still, C++ library should support that IMO (i.e. if OS is configured to compare filenames case-insensitive so should the library do).

Comment: @PowerGamer Even worse: NTFS is always case-sensitive, but the commonly used paths for accessing those files are only case-preserving. This leads to all kinds of hilarity if you create files that differ only in case...

Comment: "lexicographically" is nicely vague with no definition in the spec.  The words in a dictionary are lexicographically ordered, case does not matter :)

Answer (score 2):

You have additionally `equivalent()` function specified in 15.13, which checks if two paths resolve to the same file.

```
bool equivalent(const path& p1, const path& p2)
```

> 4. Returns: `true`, if `s1 == s2` and `p1` and `p2` resolve to the same
>      file system entity, else `false`. The signature with argument `ec`
>      returns `false` if an error occurs.

`compare()` function will use iterators and `path::operator==` to compare elements. In 8.6.13 you have written:

```
bool operator==(const path& lhs, const path& rhs) noexcept;
```

> 17. Equivalence is determined by the equivalent() non-member function,
>       which determines if two paths resolve to the same file system entity.
>       Thus equivalent("foo", "bar") will be true when both paths resolve to
>       the same file
> 18. Programmers wishing to determine if two paths are "the same" must
>       decide if "the same" means "the same representation" or "resolve to
>       the same actual file", and choose the appropriate function accordingly

So, `equivalent()` comparison is done according to system specific rules, while `compare()` checks if you have used "the same representation" to describe path.

Comment: I am afraid `equivalent()` is used for a different matter: to check if two *already existing* paths are pointing to the same physical location (i.e. to check if two symbolic links point to the same place).

Comment: @PowerGamer well, it seems that it may throw an error. However it is not mentioned explicitly what happens if you compare two non-existing paths. They also define term "pathname resolution" (4.17) and state that `equivalent()` function checks if two paths *resolve* to the same entity (see 17.) , so it's totally unclean. I think we have to wait for final standard, this is a draft after all.

Comment: @PowerGamer for me it would be logical if `equivalent("foo/bar", "foo/bar")` returned `true`, even if `"foo/bar"` does not exist. If it will not, then I will say that they have chosen rather poor function name.

Comment: @PowerGamer it would be better if `native()` returned `native_path_string` type, which could define own comparison operator instead of plain `std::basic_string` with different char widths. Current specs look like if they could not decide, if they want to be cross-platform or system-specific... :/